# Where to find help creating a dataset

Tags: data-request, images

Is there a place one can ask for help for creating a dataset?

I'm writing a thesis and I am in desperate need of people drawing images for me since they need to be of a specific kind. I have even created a site where they are guided and the image can be uploaded.

I have already tried social media, asking friends and family, but the amount of images I got are nowhere near of what would be needed to train a model. I would also be willing to pay to get help, and I have already taken a look at amazon turk, but it is rather confusing and I'm not sure if I can use it.

Answer (score 1):

How about the website https://www.upwork.com/ I'm sure there are other sites out there, this was the first I found?

You could also look [here](https://millo.co/sites-like-upwork)?